# Calling error in glmer() with family=gaussian (identity link)

Tags: r, lme4, multivariate-testing

I am trying to fix a glmm for a dataframe with 53 obs. of  17 variables. All variables are standardized, but don't follow the normal distribution and have no missing values. The str() of the data frame is something like below.

- species    : Factor w/ 19 levels "spp1","spp2",..: 5 18 12 15 19 4 6 14 16 5 ...
- association : Factor w/ 4 levels "assoA","assoB",..: 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 ...
- site      : Factor w/ 2 levels "site1","site2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
- obs.no    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
- trait1: num  0.652 0.428 0.535 0.389 0.486 ...
- trait2 : num  0.135 0.16 0.134 0.142 0.159
- (clipped trait3 to 13)

I executed the following code to check the significance between sites an association classes for the given trait.

```
model1= glmer(trait1 ~ association+site+ (1 | species),data=df6,family=gaussian)
```

and received the error given below.

> In glmer(trait1 ~ association+site+ (1 | species),data=df6,  :
>     calling glmer() with family=gaussian (identity link) as a shortcut to lmer() is deprecated; please call lmer() directly

After this I want to estimate parameters with Gauss-Hermite quadrature. Any recommendation to fix this error and code to  execute Gauss-Hermite quadrature is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Clarifying: the reason that `glmer(..., family = gaussian(link = "identity"))` is not allowed (and that `lme4` insists you use `lmer(...)` instead) is that there is no point using numerical (Gauss-Hermite) quadrature for a linear mixed model (which is exactly the special case of a GLMM with a Gaussian response and an identity link); in this case the integral can be expressed in closed form as a penalized least-squares problem (conditional on the random-effects variance/covariance parameters): see [Bates et al. 2015](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You actually posted the answer. Use lmer, not glmer:

```
model1 = lmer(trait1~association+site+(1|species), data=df6)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: But I am wondering about the help ?lmer fits a linear mixed-effects model (LMM) to data, via REML or maximum likelihood. ?glmer fits a generalized linear mixed-effects model (GLMM). Both fixed effects and random effects are specified via the model formula. Can that be same?