# How to scale log transformed data to integer values for model

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, mixed-models, data-transform

major R/coding novice here.

So I'm trying to run some generalised linear mixed models using the glmer() function. My response variable is discrete and positive but the distribution is positive/right skewed. I found that just doing a simple log() transformation gives me a nice normal distribution.

I believed I should be specifying the family as Poisson in the glmer() function but when I try to run the model with my log-transformed data R tells me I cannot do this because my values are now all non-integers. I thought perhaps if I specified a Gaussian family this would work but then I get the following error message: *calling glmer() with family=gaussian (identity link) as a shortcut to lmer() is deprecated; please call lmer() directly*.

Can anyone help me out? Should I be scaling my log-transformed data in some way to make the values integers? Or should I be doing something else entirely?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72567129/16730940 may help - it's an answer from someone encountering the same issue as you, but I don't know enough about your specific implementation to be sure it's the same cause.

Comment: I have voted to move this to https://stats.stackexchange.com as it needs statistics advice / is not a programming question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should be fitting the Poisson model by using your original, non-transformed integer data and specifying `family=poisson()` within the `glmer()` call